# Unlike length, the duration for CSS transition requires a unit even if it is 0?

Tags: css, css-transitions

The following will do CSS transition for the width first, and then the height:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("#foo").style.width = "200px";
  document.querySelector("#foo").style.height = "200px";
}, 0)
```

```css
#foo {
  transition-property: width, height;
  transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 1s;
  background: #07f;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

However, if the first `transition-delay` is changed from `0s` to `0`, then it will fail for Google Chrome and Firefox (it looks like the whole delay line is not parsed and ignored). But on Safari and MS Edge (the non-Chromium based version as of the December 2019), it worked as before:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("#foo").style.width = "200px";
  document.querySelector("#foo").style.height = "200px";
}, 0)
```

```css
#foo {
  transition-property: width, height;
  transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  transition-delay: 0, 1s;
  background: #07f;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

So which behavior is correct? Like length units, CSS treats `0` as `0px`. But why `0` is not treated as `0s` on Chrome and Firefox? Do we need a unit for `0` (such as do we need to say 0 inch or 0 cm or 0 yard, because they are all the same). Is the behavior correct on Chrome / Firefox or on Safari / MS Edge?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/time: _“Note: Although the number 0 is always the same regardless of unit, the unit may not be omitted. In other words, 0 is invalid and does not represent 0s or 0ms.”_

Comment: so `0` has a different treatment if it is time as opposed to length?

Comment: Yes, because `<time>` values are a `<dimension>` - https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#dimension: _“The general term dimension refers to a number with a unit attached to it; and is denoted by <dimension>.”_

Comment: @04FS is length a dimension too?

Comment: According to https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#length-value, yes - but with the additional specification that _“[f]or zero lengths the unit identifier is optional (i.e. can be syntactically represented as the `<number>` 0).”_

Comment: @04FS all your comments deserve to be inside an answer ;) `0` is always confusing, not only in this case